# How do I convert public RSA key (in text form) to private PPK key file?

Tags: windows-server-2003, putty, ssh-keys, winscp

I have been 'emailed' a "PUBLIC" AES 256 RSA Key (for example):

> "ssh-rsa
>   AAASDHFhdfsdSDHF2SHdf932hSDF29SDFHSDF2SDFHSDF23SHDFewhw92sdfhSDFS29843SdhsdfZSDH=
>   some@bunk"

Now, I am being asked to use it for a WinSCP SFTP session connection.

> I see in the WinSCP connection information that there is the need for
>   a "Private key file" that points to *.PPK.

**How do I convert the public key I have in text form to a private PPK key?**

The server I am working on (Windows Server 2003) has a copy of Putty. I have tried
the various options but don't see any obvious area where my public key can be converted
into the private PPK key I need.

Please advise...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get private key, not public key.

And it should work the opposite way. You generate private+public key pair and provide them with the public key.